# Фильтр HTML-таблицы посредством Python'а

Tags: html, python

Проблема состоит в том, что нет возможности использовать ни `BeautifulSoup`, ни `Elementtree` 
Идея состоит в отображении только тех рядов таблицы, дата из которых совпадает с введенной пользователем.

Есть ли ещё какие базовые хорошие инструменты для поиска данных в таблице или единственно-верным остается `regex` и его `findall`, то есть после поиска придется заново собирать всю таблицу?

Comment: почему BeautifulSoup (чистый Питон), или ElementTree (в стандартной библиотеке) не хотите использовать? Без упоминания конкретного формата дат, вопрос мало смысла имеет (в общем случае, даже для людей результат при распознавании дат может быть двусмысленный). Ещё: имеет смысл различать задачи: чтение/распознование входного формата, фильтрация во внутреннем представлении, вывод в выходном формате. Хотя иногда, один инструмент все три задачи может выполнять (pandas), но удобней (универсальней) по частям обычно работать.

Comment: Таблицу выводить из базы данных. Если необходима вставка в текст используем или шаблонизаторы или шаблонные теги.